# JavaScript link click counter

Tags: javascript, click-counting

i need a script to count link clicks on my website and count report to a flatfile/excel.

Comment: You'll need server-side code (e.g. Python, PHP, C#) to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The use of a Javascript framework like jQuery would be wise in this case.

Note that you cannot save data into a file on the client's computer. Instead, you can do an AJAX to the server, and save it via your SSI on the server into database/excel/file whatever data storage there is.

My demo will be using [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com/), [jQuery Cookie Plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/cookie) and [PHP](http://www.php.net/):

#### countdetect.js

```
jQuery(function(){
  $("a").click(function{
    var cookiename = 'linkcounter';
    if($.cookie(cookiename) == null){
       $.cookie(cookiename, 0);
    }
    $.cookie(cookiename, $.cookie(cookiename)+1);
  });
});
```

#### index.php

```
<?php

session_start();

$counter_file = 'counter';
if(!file_exists($counter_file)){
  file_put_contents($counter_file, 0);
}

$counts = (int)file_get_contents($counter_file);
file_put_contents($counter_file, $counts++);
// you can use $counts if you want to display it on the page.

?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Link Click Counter Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.cookie.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="countdetect.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="http://www.google.com/"></a><br />
    <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"></a><br />
    Link clicks: <?php echo $counts; ?>
  </body>
</html>
```