# How to check if a link has been clicked in php

Tags: php

Well I am new to this so I want to record when the user clicks on the link that php prints and query a mysql database. I know how to query the database using php already but I'm not sure if it is possible to know if the user clicked on the link.

I printed a link like so.

`print ('<a id="myLink" href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">google</a>');`

Comment: You'll have to use javascript to trigger a request to your server.  By the time the user is viewing your page, PHP's job is long done.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript link click counter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114969/javascript-link-click-counter)

Comment: Alternatively, you could link to: http://www.yoursite.com/redirect.php?www.google.com/ and implement the necessary logging and redirect functionality.

Comment: really wasn't trying to use javascript so i'll try some of these redirect.php recommendations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To track the link, you'd need to create a link tracking script on your server. i.e. linktracker.php

Then, change your code to point the link to that script, passing the forwarding url  i.e

```
<a id="myLink" href="http://mysite.com/linktracker.php?url=http://www.google.com" target="_blank">google</a>
```

In linktracker.php, you would need something like:

```
<?php 
    $url = $_GET['url'];
    // update your database click count for the url
    //  i.e UPDATE linkclicks SET clickcount = clickcount + 1 WHERE url = '$url'

    // forward the user to the end location
    header("Location: $url");
```

Comment: Seemed easiest for what I was trying to do. had to start session and session array though but it worked.

Answer (score 3):

You need to build a URL redirection mechanism.

```
$link = 'http://www.google.com';
echo '<a href="/redir.php?target="'.encodeUriComponent($link).'>google</a>';
```

then make a redir.php:

```
<?php
$targetUrl = $_REQUEST['target'];
// log this targetUrl to your MySQL database.

header( 'Location:'.$targetUrl);
```

I absolutely wouldn't do this in JavaScript if you want to try to track links shares or something of that nature.

Comment: i wouldn't recommend doing that at all unless you pay attention to security breaches. for more info seaech for CSRF attack

Comment: Um.  That doesn't even make any sense.  The 'right' way to do a URL redirection mechanism to is create a table of hashes for URLs (which prevents use from the outside), but I really have no idea how you're thinking this is some sort of CSRF.  It is a redirector, as we've been doing on the Web since the early 90s.  There isn't even any mention of a log-in system.  I think you need to do more research into CSRF.

Comment: Can't upvote you either but this concept is what I used to solve the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

add `onclick="handleClick()"` and write javascript function named `handleClick` to report the click to the server uaing ajax

Answer (score 1):

Unless the link is to your own site, you'll need to use a client-side scripting language such as JavaScript (could utilise jQuery too) to send the user's click event back to the server.